# How can I delete one of my office 365 E5 subscription, without delete both of them?

Tags: office365

I am having truble deleting my office365 e5 programe subscription.

I set up two sandbox, one of them was setteled in a wrong way.

I want to reset the sandbox or just delete it.  However, there is only one button 'delete profile' which will delete both sandboxes.